# Android AutoCompleteTextView suggestions overlapping the TextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am making an application using Google maps. I am using AutoCompleteTextView to get suggestions of places. The output is as follows :

[image]

As you can see from the image, the border of the suggestion box is overlapping the TextView. I am using custom item layout with a Textview inside a Linear Layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="#474040"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Is there a way to bring the suggestion window down and to remove or change the colour of the grayish border of the suggestion window ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this, **android:popupBackground="#EFEEEC"**// change according your border you want for the suggestion box

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/autocomplete"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/text_area"
            android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:popupBackground="#EFEEEC"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textColorHint="#9c9c9c"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:completionThreshold="1" />
```

and auto_textview.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:textColor="#333333"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

text_area9.png

[image]

Final output will look like

[image]

Hope this help you.

Comment: The problem is that in eclipse, popupBackground doesn't appear in the autocomplete suggestions so I missed it. Can you tell me how to change the border size though ? Using your method I was able to change the colour and through this entry :
[link](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.in/2012/11/styling-autocompletetextview.html) I was able to change the divider styles but the background and padding attributes in the <style> section had no effect. Is there another suggestion eclipse is not completing to set the width ?

Answer (score 6):

Was doing the same thing as in the accepted answer, but was still having the overlap issue. To fix that make this call:

```
autocompleteView.setDropDownVerticalOffset(0);
```

Comment: This one liner still works in 2023

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom drawable like

```
AutoCompleteTextView txtNames= (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.editBox);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.drawable.customlist, restList);
txtRestNames.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and add customlist as

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/cust_view"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:textSize="12dp" 
    android:singleLine="false"/>
```

Change the parameters/color to suit your needs. Try it....hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am using a custom adapter and a custom list. The code in the question is of the custom list. Still even after changing the background colour and other parameters i was not able to remove the suggestion window border.

Comment: The custom adapter implements Filterable and uses getView to display the custom list